# Why is there a delay when I do useState and useEffect to update a variable?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I saw quite a few posts about a delay between setting the state for a component, however, I'm running into this issue in a custom hook that I built. Basically, the classNames that I'm returning **are** being applied, just with a delay after the component first renders. I've tried using callback functions and useEffect with no luck. Does anyone have any ideas about why there is a small delay?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

const useScrollStyling = ref => {
    const [isScrolledToBottom, setIsScrolledToBottom] = React.useState(false);
    const [isScrolledToTop, setIsScrolledToTop] = React.useState(true);
    const [isOverflowScrollingEnabled, setIsOverflowScrollingEnabled] = React.useState(false);
    const { current } = ref;

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (current) {
            const { clientHeight, scrollHeight } = current;
            setIsOverflowScrollingEnabled(scrollHeight > clientHeight);
        }
    }, [current]);

    const handleScroll = ({ target }) => {
        const { scrollHeight, scrollTop, clientHeight } = target;
        const isScrolledBottom = scrollHeight - Math.ceil(scrollTop) === clientHeight;
        const isScrolledTop = scrollTop === 0;
        setIsScrolledToBottom(isScrolledBottom);
        setIsScrolledToTop(isScrolledTop);
    };

    return {
        handleScroll: React.useMemo(() => debounce(handleScroll, 100), []),
        scrollShadowClasses: classNames({
            'is-scrolled-top': isOverflowScrollingEnabled && isScrolledToTop,
            'is-scrolled-bottom': isScrolledToBottom,
            'is-scrolled': !isScrolledToTop && !isScrolledToBottom,
        }),
    };
};

export default useScrollStyling;
```

Comment: I think a demo of the issue would help clarify the problem you're trying to solve, but reading between the lines, you may want to try useLayoutEffect and see if that solves the issue for you.

Comment: Ah yeah, useLayoutEffect didn't work for me but I just found that this works: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node

Comment: But now I wonder...how do I get the scrollHeight and the clientHeight when doing a callback ref?

Comment: Hey! I used the same link you commented (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node) and edited the demo on sandbox --I just put console.logs of node.scrollHeight and node.clientHeight seems it printed just fine, give it a shot if you haven't already !